# ssh agent forwarding doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh

i tried to use  "ssh -A root@myhost" to connect remote server by agent forwarding;

Although i successfully connected to my remote server ;but when i pull 
code from github ,its show me an error :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

so how to fix this problem ? i can pull code with my own pc ;i am sure that i have permission to pull code

Comment: Do you have your key in `ssh-agent`? What does `ssh-add -L` returns on your host and on the `myhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Githib is not authenticating you because you either didn't setup correctly or key didn't match Githib.

You can follow this https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/ and this  or https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/.

You can prefer HTTPS URL instead of SSH/git to avoid SSH errors. https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Comment: i think i have added my own pc ssh key to github repo.

Comment: i have set git successfully ; i just want to use my own pc's permission on remote server

Comment: When remote what is the error it is showing. If same error check this https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/